# Can't Call ParentVC Func Swift

Tags: swift, parent-child

This Cell can not call parentVC's function.

```
 class MultipleAnswerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, SurveyAnswerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

var parentVC: AddQuestionViewController!

 let surveyAnswer = SurveyAnswer(answer: textField.text!, order: Int(textField.tag))
            surveyAnswers.append(surveyAnswer)
            self.parentVC?.savedAnswer(answer: surveyAnswer). //Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file Rtuk/MultipleAnswerTableViewCell.swift

 if let myParentVC = self.parentVC as? AddQuestionViewController {
                myParentVC.savedAnswer(answer: surveyAnswer)
            }
```

And the ParentVC is

```
class AddQuestionViewController: BaseViewController, SurveyTopTableViewCellDelegate, MultipleAnswerTableViewCellDelegate, SurveyTextAnswerTableViewCellDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

 func configureMultiAnswerCell(indexPath: IndexPath) -> MultipleAnswerTableViewCell {
        let postSettingsVC = PostSettingsViewController.instantiateFrom(appStoryboard: .Post)
        postSettingsVC.post = post
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MultipleAnswerTableViewCell") as! MultipleAnswerTableViewCell
        cell.parentVC = self
        return cell
    }

 func savedAnswer(answer: SurveyAnswer) {
        self.surveyAnswers.append(answer)
        print("answerLo", answer.answer)
    }



func configureTable() {
        tableView.register(MultipleAnswerTableViewCell.self)
        }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch cellTypes[indexPath.row] {
        case .fixedTop: return configureFixedTop(indexPath: indexPath)
        case .multiAnswer: return configureMultiAnswerCell(indexPath: indexPath)
        }
    }

func pickerChanged(type: SurveyType) {
        switch type {
        case .multiAnswer: cellTypes = [.fixedTop, .multiAnswer]
        case .singleAnswer: cellTypes = [.fixedTop, .singleAnswer]
        case .textAnswer: cellTypes = [.fixedTop, .textAnswer]
        }
    }
```

Somehow child never reaches to parentVC. How I configure tableview is added

I am not sure but maybe this func inside ParentVC may break it.

```
 @IBAction func saveButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MultipleAnswerTableViewCell") as! MultipleAnswerTableViewCell
        cell.mainSaveTapped(stackView: savedStack)
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the line `self.parentVC?.savedAnswer(answer: surveyAnswer)` is reached? Which method is that line in?

Comment: Yes. Breakpoint enters to this line. Then it just continues to stay inside the func.

Comment: How do you  use `configureMultiAnswerCell` post it's`cellForRowAt`

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: What u mean can not call parentVC's function? Is parentVC property is nil when u try to call its method?

Comment: @MertKöksal do you have only 2 cells ? or there are many cells ? Also Are they of different types ?

Comment: @DmytroYashchenko, you are right. How to fix that?

Comment: saveButtonTapped method is definitely weird. You just invoke random cell of the table and call its method. Can u please add mainSaveTapped to see what it does

Comment: My page is a full tableview. It consists of 2 cells. Top cell is SurveyTopTableViewCell and bottom cell is placed according to SurveyTopTableViewCell picker selection. If multipleAnswer is selected I am showing MultipleAnswerTableViewCell. saveButton is on parentVC so when it is tapped I want to save surveyAnswers to parentVC

Comment: got an fatal error at  self.parentVC.savedAnswer(answer: surveyAnswer). Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file Rtuk/MultipleAnswerTableViewCell.swift

Comment: @MertKöksal U got nil because u changed parentVC property to be forcefully  unwrapped, it is nil and u try to call it. 
The problem is that in saveButtonTapped u initialize a new instance of the cell and don't apply parentVC property at all.
I don't know why u have written its like this, but u need to call mainSaveTapped method from cell in your table. Actually u can use tableView.visibleCells.first(where: { $0 is MultipleAnswerTableViewCell }) to get first visible cell od needed type. It will start to work.

Comment: @MertKöksal But the problem of your implementation is what is the connection between tapping a save button in your VC and execution of code in some random cell inside of the table? What will be if there will be 12 cells? Which one should be taken? 
PS. Make parentVC weak and optional to avoid retain cycles, because u cause your entities to have strong references to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method like that to make it work. But, as I mentioned in comments above, it is very strange implementation and u should think about its improvement)

```
   @IBAction func saveButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let cell = tableView.visibleCells.first(where: { $0 is MultipleAnswerTableViewCell }) as? MultipleAnswerTableViewCell
        cell?.mainSaveTapped(stackView: savedStack)
    }
```

Comment: Слава Україні! брат. My wife is from Ukraine too